# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo... You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity

Tags: android, themes, splash-screen, android-splashscreen

I am implementing SplashScreen using SplashScreenApi but when I run my application splash screen appear and  then my application crashes with this message

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.splashscreenapi/com.example.splashscreenapi.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Here is my splashTheme.xml which I created by value -> new resourceFile -> styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.SplashTheme" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_baseline_baby_changing_station_24</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">200</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.SplashScreenAPI</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

here is my themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.SplashScreenAPI" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

My Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashScreenAPI"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have followed every solution but none works for me.
I would appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue when I tried to integrate an old View Activity into my Jetpack Compose application.

#### Solution 1

You can set the theme of your View Activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file like this:

```xml
     <activity
            android:name=".screens.ChatActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppTheme" />
```

#### Solution 2

In your Activity use setTheme to switch to AppTheme to display the activity like this:

```kotlin
class ChatActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityChatBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        // Switch to AppTheme for displaying the activity
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_AppTheme)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityChatBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found a solution,
Actually, I was using my app theme in the application tag of the Manifest.xml file
Here's what I was doing

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashScreenAPI"
        tools:targetApi="31">
```

now here is the problem I was creating by applying my app theme in the application tag instead of my splashScreen theme

problem:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashScreenAPI" //my app theme
```

solution:

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashTheme"// my splash theme
```

then in your activity tag in Manifest.xml set your app theme.

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashScreenApi">//my app theme>
```

also do not forget to call installSplashScreen() in your activity .java/kt file

Answer (score 0):

try this inside parent in your themes.xml

```
<style name="YourThemeName" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    
</style>
```